# EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached: With mnist data set

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I attempted to program an ANN that classifies the MNIST handwritten digit images.
Example of an ANN:
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/classify-hand-written-digits-5fdbe5d99ee7

I read other posts about this EOFError and tried all of the suggested solutions.

I located the .keras file at C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\datasets

I tried to manually delete the mnist dataset out of .keras\datasets directory and re-download it but it hasn't worked. All files are .py in the directory.
In addition, I used pip install and uninstall on all the modules needed for creating a ANN.

I coded a CNN that works using the mnist.load_data() and doesn't import the mnist module but instead uses from keras.dataset import mnist

An example of a CNN:

https://towardsdatascience.com/image-classification-in-10-minutes-with-mnist-dataset-54c35b77a38d

Is there anything I could do to make the ANN work?

File "C:/Users/wgoud/OneDrive/Desktop/organise/Python files/Pycharm/Handwriting_regoc.py", line 10, in 
train_images = mnist.train_images() # Training data images
File "C:\Users\wgoud\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mnist_*init*_.py", line 161, in train_images
return download_and_parse_mnist_file('train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz')
File "C:\Users\wgoud\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mnist_*init*_.py", line 146, in download_and_parse_mnist_file
return parse_idx(fd)
File "C:\Users\wgoud\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mnist_*init*_.py", line 111, in parse_idx
data = array.array(data_type, fd.read())
File "C:\Users\wgoud\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\gzip.py", line 276, in read
return self._buffer.read(size)
File "C:\Users\wgoud\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\gzip.py", line 482, in read
raise EOFError("Compressed file ended before the "
EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached

Comment: Use suitable abbreviation formats. Ex: 'ANN' (Artificial Neural Network) instead of 'Ann'. It helps the community to understand your question easily and provide a good answer. And please concern about the neatness of the question, too.

Comment: The error message suggests that your input is corrupted, or not a gzip stream at all.